# Solving for y(x) explicitly.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

So, I have y as an implicit function $e^{2x}= \ln\left(\frac{2(y-1)}{y+1}\right)$

Any hints to how I can get y explicitly? Any hints / help?

Comment: Exponentiate both sides, simplify, and solve for $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, $$e^x=\ln\left(\frac{2(y-1)}{y+1}\right)$$
$$e^{e^x}=\frac{2y-2}{y+1}$$ $$e^{e^x}y+e^{e^x}=2y-2$$
$$y(2-e^{e^x})=2+e^{e^x}$$
$$y=\frac{2+\large e^{e^x}}{2-\large e^{e^x}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:

First apply exponentiation with base $e$ to both sides to get rid of the $\ln$. It will look like this:

$$e^{e^{2x}} = \frac{2(y-1)}{y+1}.$$

Then multiply both sides of the equation by $y+1$, which is the demoninator on the right hand side. You will get:

$$e^{e^{2x}}(y+1) = 2(y-1).$$

Now get rid of the parantheses by multiplying into them, and you're on a good path for finding $y$.

Comment: Or rewrite the RHS $\frac{2(y-1)}{y+1}$ as $2 - \frac{4}{y+1}$ instead of multiplying $y+1$ on both sides.